# C++ error on f(void*&) call

Tags: c++

Can you please explain the error from following code please:

```
void foo(void*& param)
{
    param = new char[10];
}

void main()
{
    int* p;
    foo(p);
}

error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'void *&'
```

How may I call a function with any pointer type and change that pointer inside the function(not the value at that address, the address itself). I don't want to use templates or double pointers.

Comment: `I don't want to use templates`. Your loss.

Comment: Your compiler accepts `void main()`?

Comment: looks like your going to have a lot of memory leaks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use templates?

Comment: @smocking I want to implement some Lock mechanism that returns an address from a memory pool. There are more parameters, but this is the most simple example about my problem

Comment: I think there are several problems with this approach. If you have no need to call constructors/destructors, it's probably more portable to use `malloc()` directly. Your compiler may not handle array `delete` correctly here. If you do need them, then this code will not call them.

Comment: Or rather, not `malloc()`, but some other allocator that gets memory from your memory pool.

Comment: @mkb I will call foo_free by myself. My problems is how to call a function that returns an address from a memory pool in an elegant manner.

Comment: I use templates with locks all the time. Maybe you need to use a base class to hold the lock, but there's a few ways to do it right with templates.

Comment: If the type is known at compile time, templates are the way to go. If it's not, firstly your example is misleading and secondly you would probably be better off using malloc in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can you not pass an `int*` as argument to `f`?

The problem is that if that was allowed you would be breaking the type system. Which to be honest is exactly what you are trying to do... If you want to break the type system you will need to explicitly request it by means of a cast.

You point out in a comment that you don't want to use casts, on the other hand the compiler does not want you to break the type system. In that battle of wills, I don't think you are going to convince the compiler... it is just too stubborn.

Comment: Because he's trying to do generic programming without using templates.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: So let there be casts... the compiler will enforce type safety unless to explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone It's not generic programming. void f(void*) can be called with any pointer type and it's not generic programming:)

Comment: @felics, before continuing, make sure `f` gets an `int **` and you are passing the address of `p`. This is because `f` tries to change the pointer itself not its contents. If you write `f(p)`, `f` cannot change `p` itself.

Comment: @Felics: Yes, but the extra indirection is what breaks the type system. The extra indirection provides the tool to modify the argument to the function, and that is where things go south. For a similar example consider: `void f( const int** p ); int *p; f(&p);` which will fail to compile due to the same issue. The extra indirection provides tools to modify the argument to the function in a type unsafe way (in this case, you could make `p` point to a `const int` inside the function, and then use `*p` to modify it outside of the function).

Answer (score 2):

if you want to update your pointer, its better to pass a pointer to a pointer

```
void foo(void** param)
{
    *param = new char[10];
}

void main()
{
    void* p;
    foo(&p);
    int* p2 = (int*)p;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use casts. I want simple use for my foo function

Comment: Its a good practice to use the same type for pointers.
in your code you allocated 10 bytes of data and than try to change it to int*. a int is 4 byte long. so you want to allocate an array of size of 2.5.
if you want to change the pointer type, you must use casting.

Comment: You're rejecting all the solutions that actually answer your question. It simply isn't going to get simpler than this.

Comment: If you're using `void*` to do anything that isn't trivial, **you will need to use casts.**

Comment: @MichaelWilson I reject the answers that make foo call more awkward - like this where I need to declare 2 variables to call the function.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone It seems the right solution, to use casts. If MS guys used casts I think there is no elegant solution for this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Casts are the C way. They're great if your compiler doesn't support templates or does a bad job of it, like several did during the 90's.

Comment: @felics, write in C if you want to avoid the cast!

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, try compiling this: `int main()
{
        int *a;
        void *b;
        a = b;
        return 0;
}`

Comment: @Shahbaz: Ah, good point. I forgot C lets you assign `void*` to another pointer; C++ does not allow this (`error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*'`).

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, which is odd given how your top answer with more than 50 up-votes is about migrating from C++ to C!

Comment: No, it was about "What capabilities do I lose when I migrate from C++ to C". Not the same thing as advocating C. As should be clear from that other answer, I actually prefer C++ and its stricter typing rules and templating to C's blind trust and too-clever-by-half uses of `#define`, and see the "just use C" crowd as the modern form of the "write it all in assembly" crowd. C doesn't just put a lot of trust in the programmer, it won't let you *not* trust yourself... and every other programmer.